# Rails Devise, No route matches '/users/sign_out' -> SignOut/Logout Routes problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a app using devise to login/out, and view/create profiles.  As of yet users may create and delete profiles although there is only supposed to be one profile per user.  I have set up my routes just about without problems until comes the SignOut/LogOut from the whole app.  Ultimately the error log is all I can decipher, and seems that routes.rb needs some modification for this to work, but I am stumped.  Here are the errors and routes.rb:
/log/production.log:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-01-26 01:56:53 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"):
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions" }

resources :profiles, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

devise_scope :user do
authenticated :user do
root to: 'profiles#index', as: :authenticated_root
get '/profiles/new' => 'profiles#new'
match '/profiles' => 'profiles#create', via: [:get, :post]
get '/profiles/:id' => 'profiles#show'
get '/profiles/:id/edit' => 'profiles#edit'
match '/profiles/:id' => 'profiles#update', via: [:get, :post]
delete '/profiles' => 'profiles#destroy', via: [:get, :post]
end
unauthenticated :user do
root to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
match '/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]
delete '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
end
end
```

I read that using resources :users may affect devise sessions controller, in that I would need a UsersController, however haven't included resources :users in my routes, and/or for a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

You placed the sign-out route in the `unauthenticated` block in your `routes.rb`

```
unauthenticated :user do
  # ..
  delete '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

What doesn't makes sense, only authenticated users can sign out. Just move that method into the `authenticated :user` block above:

```
authenticated :user do
  # ..
  delete '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```